# Access times for different partitions on same hard disk

Tags: partition, performance, virtualization

I have partitions, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.

`/` is mounted on `/dev/sda1`, while all other data is on `sda2` which has more size allocated to it.

I want to save the virtual machine images (`VirtualBox Disk Image`)  on `sda2`.

My question is, should I expect any difference in performance if I access data from the second partition?

`tl;dr` -- is there is any difference in performance if I have to access data located on a different partition? If yes, does it make sense to decrease seek times by moving data to `/dev/sda1`?

Please note that this may be one of those micro-optimization issues but I want to squeeze every possible inch of performance I can for the VMs.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, should I expect any difference in performance if I
>   access data from the second partition?

Whether or not you see any difference depends on filesystem type and the underlying device.

There should be no ***noticeable*** difference if it is the same device, same fstype.

Having the VM on a separate filesystem is certainly useful for backing up by partition or filesystem.

If you were to put the VM filesystem on a separate device, like a an SSD or fast, high RPM HD
Then you might see a noticeable difference.

As always, it depends.

How much activity is taking place on /?
What kind of activity? I/O intensive? Same questions for VM.